# tikz: grid corners

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Apologies if this is a duplicate. It would seem like it would be a well-known problem, but I was unable to track a solution.

In words: the grid lines do not extend enough to form sharp corners. I would like sharp corners. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
  \draw (0, 0) grid (1, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I do not know why it is not default for grid, but it helps to set the `line cap` to `rect`.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line cap=rect] (0, 0) grid (1, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. Indeed, if anyone knows why this isn't the default, please chime in.

Comment: @PatrickT You can also try `round` (instead of `rect`). The initial value is `butt` for `grid` and for all other drawing operations as in PDF standard.